# HTMX detecting a click outside a component

Tags: htmx

I need to create a header in htmx with a notifications icon. when I click on the icon, a window with the notifications opens in an empty div with the hx-target. I need that when I click outside the window, it closes. how can I do this using htmx?

I tried to use a js function but it didn’t work. I need to do this with just HTMX if possible

Answer (score 0):

i tried to do this:

https://vue.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-cvuishell--header-base-with-actions-and-right-panels

and "click outside" looks like this

```
function notifictionPanel(e) {
  let npanel = htmx.find("#notif-panel")
  if (npanel.attributes['aria-hidden'].value === 'true') {
    htmx.addClass(npanel, "bx--header-panel--expanded")
    npanel.setAttribute("aria-hidden", false)
  } else {
    htmx.removeClass(npanel, "bx--header-panel--expanded")
    npanel.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true)
  }
  /*Add event*/
  let clickOutSide = htmx.on("click",
    function(evt){
      const isBtn = evt.target.closest("#header-notification_btn") ? true : false;
      const ariaHidden = npanel.attributes['aria-hidden'].value
      if (ariaHidden === 'false' && !isBtn && evt.target.id != 'notif-panel') {
        htmx.removeClass(npanel, "bx--header-panel--expanded")
        npanel.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true)
        // Remone event clickOutSide
        htmx.off("click", clickOutSide);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can entirely do it with htmx alone. You have to decide what you want to do to actually 'close' the the notification panel: do you want to simply close it or empty its contents? If clicking on a notifications icon is making an a server request, I would recommend just clearing the notification panel (since subsequent clicks will be making new requests anyway).

To implement this, you can simply attach a click event on the body and check if the target is not the panel (you don't want to close the panel when you click inside it). If it's not, you can close it.

While you can listen to events with `hx-on`, I don't think you can run htmx specific logic to manipulate the DOM (I, too, would be glad to learn of this). You will have to write a line of JavaScript code to pull it off with `hx-on` attribute:

```
<body hx-on:click=" event.target.getAttribute('id') === 'notif-panel'? document.getElementById('notif-panel').innerHTML = '' : null "....
```

But writing JavaScript in html tags, in my opinion, looks ugly. You can explore [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/) (was created by the same people who created htmx, so it shares the same philosophy as htmx but it's great for DOM manipulation.

Or, just do it with vanilla JavaScript, it shouldn't be more than three lines of code with the approach I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use [_hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/docs/) (which is part of the htmx ecosystem) then you can add a hyperscript attribute to the notification window itself:

```
<div id="notification-pane"
     _="on click from elsewhere add .hidden to me">
</div>
```

It's pretty self-explanatory, but this is adding an event listener for a click event originating outside the notification window, and it handles that event by adding a CSS class `hidden` to that div. If you want to completely remove it from the DOM, you would say `remove me` instead of `add .hidden to me`.

Hyperscript works really well alongside htmx. You handle server interactions with htmx and client-side interactivity with hyperscript.